# Get Locust IO info for each generated user

Tags: python, performance-testing, locust

The company I work on compromises to deliver 99% of their service responses in less than 1 second and 99.9% or their responses in less that 2 seconds. **How can I make Locust report if this rule has been broken for any of the virtual users?**

- My first approach would be to make a method in my user (inherited
  from locust.HttpLocust) that will detect when this event happens and
  record it in a user-based log. I think this would work but if I have
  1000 user it means I will have 1000 different log files.
- A second approach would be to create a single event log, but I guess
  that would require me to deal with asynchronos IO handling. I guess
  there must be a more pythonesque way.

Locust and performance newbie here. Sorry if my question is misguided.

Answer (score 0):

You can add duration checks at the end of each `@task` like:

```
@task
   def service_request(self):
       r = self.client.get("/your/service/path")
       assert r.elapsed < datetime.timedelta(seconds = 1), "Request took more than 1 second"
```

This way you will have a report on individual HTTP Requests level with regards to which ones are successful and which tool > 1 second.

More information: [Locust Assertions - A Complete User Manual](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-assertions-a-complete-user-manual)

---

Alternatively you can try considering running your test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Locust/) tool as a wrapper. Taurus has powerful and flexible [Pass/Fail Criteria](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) subsystem which analyses the results on-the-fly and returns a non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) which can be used as an indicator of failure for shell scripts or continuous integration solutions.